# Microservice architecture Flaws

Tags: architecture, microservices, restful-architecture

We are facing performance related issues with microservice architecture.

Let's say there is microservice for user and account management. which have api's like

```
GET /users/{id} 
GET /users       (arrount 6 million users)

GET /accounts/{accountId}
GET /accounts 
and Other Operations on user and account
```

We have other microservice which track's user activities and list all the activities done by the user in his last login.

```
GET /user/activity/{userId}  (on an average 1000 to 10000 records)
```

We have protal for sales and marketing team to show individual user activities and  user info and account info based on search criteria,

```
let's say search criteria is like : get all user activies who are located in colombia
Algorithm : 

1)Get /users ? location = colombia
2)then for individual user Get /user/activity/{userId}
```

it is like joining two tables from different databases.

it is very slow and creating lot of performance issues.

what i though of is replicating user table in other microservice by a job which makes sure it is up to date and using only one api like

```
GET /user/activities?location=colombia.
```

but replicating a table(user) is breaking the micro-service architecture main fundamentals

is there any other way to do it or support this type of filter criteria which join's tables from different micro-services.

Comment: Why dont you bulk up your 2nd call? Meaning pass all the user ids you deem relevant at once? Also did you think about implementing a paging mechanism?

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann thank's for pointing it out. we have pagination in place.but there are some opeartion like csv download by search criteria in those cases we are planning to do via sending an email link for downloading and rest you know. is there any other way to handle this kind of scenario's where data from multiple datasources need to be joined.in my question i have taken simple scenario.but,there are lot of complex scenario's where pagination also will not help.

Comment: If you end up with a lot of use cases that force you to join data from multiple services you should rethink your service boundaries. It is hard to find the right boundaries, but in general you want services that represent a self-containing business use case and not entity-related (for example you don't want "user service", "product service", etc.). Please read: https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in using `Command Query Responsibility Segregation`

See this [implementing queries that need to retrieve data owned by multiple services](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html).

You can draw much inspirations from [this example](https://github.com/eventuate-examples/eventuate-examples-java-customers-and-orders) (Customers and Orders example of http://eventuate.io/).

Comment: Wouldn't [graphql](https://graphql.org/) be an alternative solution (and more extensible) to this as it gives the power to the api client to fetch what ever data it needs?

Comment: Probably but I'm not sure which is faster between the [graphql](https://graphql.org/) and [CRQS](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html). AFAIK in regard to microservices, [CRQS](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html) and [event sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html) are considered best practices for joining tables from different services.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid slowness by multiple things .
for step number 2 "2)then for individual user Get /user/activity/{userId}"

- instead of sending user by user you can send multiple users in one call .
- you can have parallel threads to retrieve multiple users chunks on same time.
- if you have a web interface you can use pagination which really help .

Comment: thanks for answering!. but can you please go through the question once and recheck whether have you answered it?.